# prompt parenthesis (myenv)$ seems to disappear in newest conda

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

Prompt parenthesis `(myenv)$` seems to disappear in newest conda.

#### Current situation:

```
john@myPC:~$ conda activate myenv
john@myPC:~$
```

It supposed to be:

```
john@myPC:~$ conda activate myenv
(myenv) john@myPC:~$
```

What I have tried and failed so far.

#### Solution A:

```
$ conda config // init .condarc file
$ conda config --set changeps1 True
```

Then re-login bash, not working

#### Solution B:

```
put `changeps1: true` in `.condarc` file
```

#### Solution C:

```
put `export CONDA_CHANGEPS1=true` in `.bashrc`
```

Please give me some suggestions.

OS: ubuntu 18.04

Anaconda Installer: [64-Bit (x86) Installer - Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh)
Terminal: GNU bash, version 4.4.19

Here is my `conda info`

```
$ rm ~/.condarc
$ conda init --dry-run -vv
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(150): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.gateways.subprocess:subprocess_call(48): executing>> /home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/python --version


/home/{user}/.bashrc
--- 

+++ 

@@ -129,7 +129,7 @@

     \eval "$__conda_setup"
 else
     if [ -f "/home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
-        . "/home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
+# . "/home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
         CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
     else
         \export PATH="/home/{user}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
@@ -150,3 +150,19 @@

 ##############################
 export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:/usr/lib/nvidia-396:${PATH:+:${PATH}}
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-396:/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
+
+# >>> conda initialize >>>
+# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
+__conda_setup="$('/home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
+if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
+    eval "$__conda_setup"
+else
+    if [ -f "/home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
+        . "/home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
+    else
+        export PATH="/home/{user}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
+    fi
+fi
+unset __conda_setup
+# <<< conda initialize <<<
+
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xonsh/conda.xsh
no change     /home/{user}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      /home/{user}/.bashrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

```
john@myPC:~$ conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/john/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/john/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : /home/john/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/john/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/john/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/john/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/john/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Linux/4.15.0-46-generic ubuntu/18.04.2 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
john@myPC:~$ conda config
john@myPC:~$ cat .condarc
{}
john@myPC:~$ conda activate myenv
john@myPC:~$ conda info

     active environment : molhack
    active env location : /home/john/anaconda3/envs/molhack
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /home/john/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : /home/john/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/john/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/john/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/john/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/john/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Linux/4.15.0-46-generic ubuntu/18.04.2 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
john@myPC:~$ conda config --set changeps1 True
john@myPC:~$ cat ~/.condarc
changeps1: true
john@myPC:~$
// 
// (myenv)john@myPC:~$ are missing
//
```

Comment: `conda info` added.

Comment: `conda init --dry-run -vv` had no output? Also, your shell is bash, correct?

Comment: sorry, I just added the output of `conda init --dry-run -vv`, and yes, I am using GNU bash, version 4.4.19.

Answer (score 1):

The output for `conda init` is strange. In a properly configured installation, it should show `no change`, but yours indicates that it would alter your `.bashrc`. You could just try letting `conda init` do its work, however, the proposed changes appear to show that this would result in multiple Conda managed regions.  Instead, I would try

1. Back up `.bashrc`
2. Remove from `.bashrc` any Conda managed sections. Also, make sure that you don't have any sections that add your `/home/{user}/anaconda3/bin` to path (as per [v4.4 recommendations](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).
3. Run `conda init -vv`. The flag is just there to see what it does.
4. Start a fresh bash shell.